# Unrecognized token in SQLite Query

Tags: android

I am doing a query in SQLite where i want to fecth records whitch create date is greater then create date
**My Query is:**

```
String selection=String.valueOf(new Date().getTime());
        String[] selectionArgument = {selection};

        ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
        Cursor urlDownload = contentResolver.query(
                StubContract.Schedule.schedule_uri, StubContract.Schedule.PROJECTION_MESSAGE,
                StubContract.Schedule.CREATE_DATE+">=?",
              selectionArgument,
                null);
```

**and error Log is:**

[image]

Please help how to resolve this Error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change

```
String[] selectionArgument = {selection};
```

to

```
String[] selectionArgument = new String[]{selection};
```

Comment: Can you also show what is the right side of the error. Copy the complete error here @GhanshyamSharma